# Capital E is suddenly a sticky modifier in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Sometime in the last couple of weeks something somehow changed on my system - every time I type capital E in emacs, it is interpreted as a modifier, and is sticky; it behaves just like escape does but it is not escape (proven through describe-key-briefly).

Nothing in my emacs config has changed.

I am running emacs for osx (which is down?!?) GNU Emacs24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-20 on builder10-9.porkrind.org

Needless to say, I don't want this behavior and want to turn it off.

**--EDIT--**

D'oh - it turns out I just noticed this is a side affect to a change I made a couple weeks ago. Here is the patch to my config that fixes it

```
(defun set-org-mode-bindings ()
-        (local-set-key (kbd "ESC-M-<RET>") 'org-insert-heading-respect-content)
         (local-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'org-back-to-indentation))
 (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'set-org-mode-bindings)
```

Why this line A) doesn't work and B) causes the behavior?

Comment: If you run it as `emacs -q` and it does not misbehave, it's a problem with your user config.  Bisect your config to find the source of the problem.  If it misbehaves with `emacs -q` (or `emacs -Q`), then it's a problem with core emacs.

Comment: What @jpkotta said. I'm placing a bet now...

Comment: Misbehavior prevented by `emacs -q` could also be a bug in a package installed from e.g. ELPA.

Comment: Forgot about -q... Thanks, I'm looking into my ELPA pkgs now.

Comment: have narrowed it down to only org-mode too.